# How to set "Break on All Exceptions", from a Package

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-extensions

I want to make an extension to quickly toggle breaking on CLR exceptions in debugger.
I have made tried several approaches, neither of which is satisfactory.

Here is what I have already tried:

1. `ExceptionSettings.SetBreakWhenThrown` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte90.exceptionsettings.setbreakwhenthrown.aspx))
   This is extremely slow (see [this Connect issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/530408/abysmal-performance-when-changing-debugger-break-on-throw-settings)). I have tried approaches from question "[Toggle “Break when an exception is thrown.” using macro or keyboard shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958011/toggle-break-when-an-exception-is-thrown-using-macro-or-keyboard-shortcut)" and neither seem to work reliably: in most cases only top level checkbox gets set, and it does not actually break on exceptions when debugging.
2. Call `DTE.ExecuteCommand("Debug.Exceptions")` to show the window, and call `SetWindowsHookEx` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) just before that to intercept it before it appears (so that there is no flash to the user). This seems possible as I was able to intercept the message and get `HWND`. But it seems hacky and window is not that easy to manipulate properly (it has some weird combination of `SysListView32` with custom checkboxes and `SysTreeView32`). So I am leaving it as a last chance solution.
3. Somehow get `IDebugEngine2` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/bb145310.aspx)) for managed code and call `IDebugEngine2.SetException` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb162170.aspx)) at the start of the debugging session. This seems possible, but I am having problems getting a debug engine. I have tried approach with `IVsLoader` described [on MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/3b75164e-31c4-49c8-923f-2b91be49080a), but I am pretty sure it gives me a new instance unrelated to the debugging session.

   I have also asked the question here: "[Visual Studio: How to get IDebugEngine2 from VS Package (except IVsLoader)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524038/visual-studio-how-to-get-idebugengine2-from-vs-package-except-ivsloader)", but did not get a solution.

   I have tried using `IVsDebugger.AdviseDebugEventCallback` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsdebugger.advisedebugeventcallback%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)) and passing in implementation of `IDebugEventCallback2` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb145585(v=vs.80).aspx)), but I am always getting `null` for `pEngine` (and no `IDebugEngineCreateEvent2` either).

   I do get `IDebugSessionCreateEvent2` (undocumented?) and can get `IDebugSession2` from it, but its `SetException` call always gives me an `HRESULT` for wrong argument, so I might be missing something here (calling `SetException` on engine from `IVsLoader` gives OK, just does not work).

Is there some other approach that is better than those or have I missed something in the existing ones?

---

**UPDATE/NOTE:**
If you found this question because you want a faster "Break on All Exceptions", I have made a free extension you can get from Visual Studio Gallery: [Exception Breaker](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/50091e25-9e75-40d3-9780-a05892f474de).

Comment: You deserve more than just +1 for the effort you put into this question, so I put in the past 3 hours working on a potential solution. :) I believe it may only apply to VS2012 right now but hopefully we can get it going in 2010 as well.

Comment: I really appreciate your help! My skills currently hit their limit at low-level debugging, so I was stuck there. I hope this extension will save people much more time than we spent researching it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The automation interfaces are *out of the question*. In an attempt to improve performance using them, I created a cache from exception group to `ExceptionSettings` object and exception name to the `ExceptionSetting` object. This allowed me to bypass `ExceptionSettings.Item` for rapid lookup of individual exceptions for calling `SetBreakWhenThrown`, but unfortunately the internal implementation of `SetBreakWhenThrown` includes a call to validate the arguments, which in turn triggers an internal enumeration process that plagues this entire approach. The cache is about 4 times faster than code not using a macro, but we're still talking about code that will hang the IDE for several minutes...

**NOTE: The instructions below were only tested so far with Visual Studio 2012.**

Stepping through `SetBreakWhenThrown` in disassembly view revealed that the critical internal call (after validation) is `sdm::CDebugManager::SetException`. It turns out that the shell debugger (`SVsShellDebugger` service which you cast to `IVsDebugger`) implements `IDebuggerInternal` which provides access to the current `IDebugSession3`. This property was non-null after I opened a solution but before I started debugging.

```
IDebuggerInternal debugger = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SVsShellDebugger)) as IDebuggerInternal;
IDebugSession3 session = debugger != null ? debugger.CurrentSession : null;
```

Note: The `IDebuggerInternal` interface is defined in:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Interop.Internal, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
```

Using information returned by `EnumSetExceptions`, I created a structure that successfully alters the settings for a CLR exception! Call `IDebugSession3.SetException` to *enable* the debugger halting when the exception is thrown.

```
EXCEPTION_INFO[] exceptionInfo =
{
    new EXCEPTION_INFO()
    {
        bstrExceptionName = typeof(NullReferenceException).FullName,
        bstrProgramName = null,
        dwCode = 0,
        pProgram = null,
        guidType = VSConstants.DebugEnginesGuids.ManagedOnly_guid,
        dwState = enum_EXCEPTION_STATE.EXCEPTION_STOP_FIRST_CHANCE
            | enum_EXCEPTION_STATE.EXCEPTION_STOP_SECOND_CHANCE
            | enum_EXCEPTION_STATE.EXCEPTION_JUST_MY_CODE_SUPPORTED
            | enum_EXCEPTION_STATE.EXCEPTION_STOP_USER_FIRST_CHANCE
            | enum_EXCEPTION_STATE.EXCEPTION_STOP_USER_UNCAUGHT
    }
};
hr = session.SetException(exceptionInfo);
```

To *disable* the debugger halting, use `IDebugSession3.RemoveSetException` instead.

Comment: This is amazing, thanks a lot!   I actually found that `AdviseDebugEventCallback` + `IDebugSessionCreateEvent2` work just as well, as long as I use your flags combination instead of  `enum_EXCEPTION_STATE.EXCEPTION_STOP_ALL`. And the best part is that Exception Dialog also notices that change, so I do not have to replace it in the first version.

Comment: Found an issue. When I call `SetException`, this affects contents of `Debug->Exceptions` and generally works, but not during the current session. For example, if I open a console app, the session (let's call it Session1) is immediately created for `*.vshost.exe` — then when I press `Run`, same session is used, then it is re-created on `Stop` (Session2). So while `Debug->Exceptions` show my setting, Session1 does not break on it — but Session2 does even without setting it again.

Comment: So `SetException` seems to affect some internal option persisted between sessions, but the current session does not reload this option immediately. I assume `Debug->Exceptions` calls some kind of reinitialize/update method, but I can not find anything suitable in the APIs.

Comment: EPIC WIN: Wasted some hours on unmanaged debugging (never did that before), found out I have to call `session.RemoveAllSetExceptions` with `Guid.Empty` (!) beforehand.

Comment: Another question: I switched to using `IDebuggerInternal` in the latest version of the extension, but I can not find the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Interop.Internal, Version=11.0.0.0` in my VS2012 (Premium). I found it in VS2010, but the interface is different: I managed to solve this, but I am still curious where is that file for VS2012.

Comment: OK I found it, it is in GAC ;)

Comment: In VS 2017 there is no `*.vshost.exe` anymore. So everything is much simpler now. `SetException` affects Exception list window (non-modal) and current session too.